# Amazon RDS, filter on replicated databases

Tags: amazon-web-services, replication, amazon-rds

While setting up amazon RDS as slave, I've noticed that there is no option to specify which databases to replicate. I've found some threads on SO from a few years back where it says there's no such option.

Just want to see if anyone managed to do that in 2017? Is it that hard to allow such options ?

Comment: There's no such option

Comment: *"Is it that hard to allow such options?"*  RDS is a managed service.  Filtered replication is a very effective mechanism for allowing novices to shoot themselves in the foot.  Those two things don't go well together.

Comment: I have different POV on this, I don't see how adding filtering would confuse the novice users. Specially if filtering is off by default and is allowed on regular db instance on a vps, it's part of the learning curve.